# R: Aggregate from two data frames on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, aggregate, multiple-columns

I have a data frame called "e" that contains posts froma platform, with unique entry_id and member_id:

```
row.    member_id   entry_id        timestamp
1       1            a              2008-06-09 12:41:00
2       1            b              2008-07-14 18:41:00
3       1            c              2010-07-17 15:40:00
4       2            d              2008-06-09 12:41:00
5       2            e              2008-09-18 10:22:00
6       3            f              2008-10-03 13:36:00
```

I have another data frame called "c", that contains comments:

```
row.    member_id   comment_id      timestamp
1       1            I              2007-06-09 12:41:00
2       1            II             2007-07-14 18:41:00
3       1            III            2009-07-17 15:40:00
4       2            IV             2007-06-09 12:41:00
5       2            V              2009-09-18 10:22:00
6       3            VI             2010-10-03 13:36:00
```

I want to count all the comments a member wrote before he posted an entry. So the data frame "e" should look like this. Only mind the years when reading the example. The solution however should cover minutes too:

```
row.    member_id   entry_id    prev_comment_count  timestamp
1       1            a              2              2008-06-09 12:41:00
2       1            b              2              2008-07-14 18:41:00
3       1            c              3              2010-07-17 15:40:00
4       2            d              1              2008-06-09 12:41:00
5       2            e              1              2008-09-18 10:22:00
6       3            f              0              2008-10-03 13:36:00
```

I alrady tried with the following function:

```
functionPrevComments <- function(givE)  nrow(subset
(c, (as.character(givE["member_id"]) == c["member_id"]) & 
(c["timestamp"] <= givE["timestamp"])))
```

But when I try to sapply it, I get the error

```
"Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "<=""
```

I used the "$" Operator for referenncing the colums I need before but then I got

```
"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors "
```

How do I apply my function correctly or is there another and better solution the solve my problem ?

Best Regards,

Nikolas

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different option. Make sure you have both "timestamp" columns converted to POSIXct-class before running the code.

```
e$prev_comment_count <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(e)), function(i) {
  nrow(c[c$member_id == e$member_id[i] & c$timestamp < e$timestamp[i], ])
})

e
#  row. member_id entry_id           timestamp prev_comment_count
#1    1         1        a 2008-06-09 12:41:00                  2
#2    2         1        b 2008-07-14 18:41:00                  2
#3    3         1        c 2010-07-17 15:40:00                  3
#4    4         2        d 2008-06-09 12:41:00                  1
#5    5         2        e 2008-09-18 10:22:00                  1
#6    6         3        f 2008-10-03 13:36:00                  0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e$type <- "entry"
c$type <- "comment"

names(e) <- c("row", "member_id", "action_id", "timestamp", "type")
names(c) <- c("row", "member_id", "action_id", "timestamp", "type")

DF <- rbind(e,c)
DF$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(DF$timestamp, 
                           format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
DF <- DF[order(DF$member_id, DF$timestamp),]
DF$count <- as.integer(ave(DF$type, 
                           DF$member_id, 
                           FUN = function(x) cumsum(x == "comment")))
DF[DF$type == "entry",]

#  row member_id action_id           timestamp  type count
#1   1         1         a 2008-06-09 12:41:00 entry     2
#2   2         1         b 2008-07-14 18:41:00 entry     2
#3   3         1         c 2010-07-17 15:40:00 entry     3
#4   4         2         d 2008-06-09 12:41:00 entry     1
#5   5         2         e 2008-09-18 10:22:00 entry     1
#6   6         3         f 2008-10-03 13:36:00 entry     0
```

If this is not fast enough, it can be improved with data.table or dplyr.